# Finding the coefficient of a term of a specific power after polynomial exponentiation?

Tags: probability, summation, products

I'm trying to write a probability function involving a 5-sided dice that has face values 2-5.  I need to find the probability that the sum of n rolls of the dice equals k.  I know I can find this through the coefficient of the x^k term after evaluating the following expression:

$$\prod_{k=1}^n(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)\ $$

I'd like to not have to search through the terms manually. Is there a different expression that can simply produce the coefficient value?

Comment: [Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) (generalization of binomial theorem), probably isn't helpful though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain the coefficient it is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series.

> We obtain for $k\geq 2n$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{k}]}&\color{blue}{(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^n}\\
> &=[x^{k}]x^{2n}(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{k-2n}]\frac{(1-x^5)^n}{(1-x)^n}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^{k-2n}]\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-x^{5j})\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{-n}{l}(-x)^l\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j[x^{k-2n-5j}]\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{n+l-1}{l}x^l\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{k-2n}{5}\rfloor}\binom{n}{j}\binom{k-n-5j-1}{k-2n-5j}(-1)^j}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $x^{2n}$.
- In (2) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ and use the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* formula.
- In (3) we expand the numerator  using the binomial theorem. We also apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the  *coefficient of* operator and apply the same rule as in (2). We also apply the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}.
- In (5) we select the coefficient accordingly and restrict the upper limit of the sum since the exponent $k-2n-5j$ of $x$ has to be non-negative.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Worked perfectly :)

Comment: @RyanLehmkuhl: You're welcome! :-)